# Update Activity class from complete different class that extends AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Have done some reading already but have not found a thread/article I felt I understood to help me with my issue.

In an activity in my Android application I have a simple ListView that contains the title of images and a ProgressBar for each image that needs to be downloaded. The logic to download these images are and must be in a separate non activity classes that fire off each image that needs to be downloaded in its own AsyncTask. Currently I am able to see that I am able to download all the images in the background at once but that is it.

I'm wondering how I can update that ListView upon progress(so I can do 10% complete etc.)/completion of each image from those AsyncTasks?

I'm pretty lost here.. I have done some research already and found ThreadPoolExecutor, would this help? Any suggestions/guides/articles would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using seperate class for AsyncTask?

From the Android Docs,

[`AsyncTask must be subclassed to be used.`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Because Class A (the activity class) calls a function in Class B (REST logic/AsyncTask). In Class B there is a loop that executes AsyncTask for each image to be downloaded. Then Class B needs to update the UI (but I don't think this is allowed).

Comment: so why don't you create a Interface or a BroadcastReceiver that update your UI when your AsynTask is completed.